# iOS Property not found on object of type 'AppDelegate *'

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have two `viewControllers` accessing a `NSNumber` on the `AppDelegate`.  One of them can see it, and the other can't.  I am totally confused by this.

The one with the problem has this code.

```
AppDelegate *dataStore = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
dataStore.downHUD = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(float)progress];
```

The other has this.

```
AppDelegate *dataStore = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
dataStore.downHUD = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(float)0];
```

Both imports the AppDelegate in the .m file but I end up with

> Property 'downHUD' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate *'

with the first one.
Anyone that can help me see what's wrong?

I copied and pasted a lot of code into the `AppDelegate` by mistake, that has been corrected.  Is there some sort of link that could got broken?

Comment: Make sure the `@end` is in your AppDelegate.h file, with no "trash" following, and that the statement prior to it is properly terminated with a `;`, if appropriate.

Comment: @Hot Licks That's all in order.  Alkimake imported everywhere.  Still stuck. Can't figure why it works one day and then not.

Comment: Also do "show info" on both view controller .m files and make sure they're both marked as Objective-C type files.

Comment: They both look good. One is C header and the other Objective-C sourse for all three classes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe there is no such property in your `AppDelegate` class.

In your AppDelegate.h under interface declaration you need to have

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber* downHUD;
```

In your AppDelegate.m under implementation declaration you need to have

```
@synthesize downHUD;
```

In this manner you define accessors (getter and setter) to access an instance variable called `downHUD`. This accessors are public and you can do

```
dataStore.downHUD = ...
```

Maybe this could be the error. But without `AppDelegate` code it's difficult to understand what is going on.

Hope it helps.

**Edit:**

It's no a good strategy to access data within the application delegate. I suggest you to use singletons like [singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html)

**Edit 2:**

```
@interface SingletonModel : NSObject {
    NSNumber* downHUD_;
}

+ (id)sharedInstance;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber* downHUD;

@end

#import "SingletonModel.h"

@implementation SingletonModel

@synthesize downHUD = downHUD_;

static SingletonModel *sharedInstance = nil;

+ (SingletonModel *)sharedInstance {
    if (sharedInstance == nil) {
        sharedInstance = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
    }

    return sharedInstance;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {

    }

    return self;
}

-(void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone*)zone {
    return [[self sharedInstance] retain];
}

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    return self;
}

- (id)retain {
    return self;
}

- (NSUInteger)retainCount {
    return NSUIntegerMax;
}

- (oneway void)release {

}

- (id)autorelease {
    return self;
}

@end
```

To set your model:

```
SingletonModel* model = [SingletonModel sharedInstance];
model.downHUD = ...
```

To read your model:

```
SingletonModel* model = [SingletonModel sharedInstance];
NSNumber* n = model.downHUD;
```

For other info read [iphone-code-snippet-the-singleton-pattern](http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2010/04/iphone-code-snippet-the-singleton-pattern/) and [singleton-classes](http://iphone.galloway.me.uk/iphone-sdktutorials/singleton-classes/). About Singletons you can find in apple documentation at [Cocoa Fundamentals Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW32) and at [Singleton](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Singleton.html).

Comment: I have `@property (copy, readwrite) NSNumber *downHUD;` in the .h and it's synthsized in the .m file. The strange thing is that one of the files see it and not the other.

Comment: Great answer, and +1 for using singletons for this instead of stuffing the app delegate.

Comment: @JorgenA you could try to clean derived data for your project but your problem is quite strange [xcode-4-deriveddata-and-cleaning-the-build-directory.html](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/9/14/xcode-4-deriveddata-and-cleaning-the-build-directory.html)

Comment: The strange thing it was working just fine until I screwed up the AppDelegate. I have restored everything to the snapshot when it was happy.I know that using a singleton is better, but a lot of work as I understand it. Does it have to sit in it's own file?

Comment: No, it's not a lot of work. Yes, you have to implement .h and .m for a singleton class. The link I provided for singleton explains it very well.

Comment: I'm only trying to pass a countdown from one view to another. Isn't it a bit of overkill to set up a whole .m and .h for that?

Comment: I think not. Maybe you could use for further developments. But if you have two controllers(say A and B) and you create B from A, then you can inject directly that values to B from A like `b.downHUD = ...`.

Comment: B actually need a count up from A, and the only way I could get it to work was via the AppDelegate ( until I broke it).

Comment: Thanks Flex. I'll get on it in the morning.

Comment: Found a simpler singleton as I'm using ARC, and it works great. Thanks Flex for putting me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Your two view controllers may refer to different AppDelegate code. Even though the Xcode Project Navigator shows only one set of AppDelegate files, and Jump to Definition shows the same AppDelegate class definition in both cases, one of the view controllers may actually have different delegate code.

I had this very problem with a delegate class definition, where some member variables were only available in one view controller but not in the other.

Right-click on each ViewController.m file in the Project Navigator, and use Show in Finder to see whether they are both in the same location as the desired AppDelegate files. If not, move the VC files to the correct location and add them to the project.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using expo this is how to get rid of the bug.
"reactDelegate" was introduced in sdk 44.0.0 so if you're using sdk 43.0.0
here's is how your code should look in your "AppDelegate.m" from line 35 - 46.

```
RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge moduleName:@"main" initialProperties:nil];
rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
rootViewController.view = rootView;
self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

[super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have imported the header files then it should work. Did you try to clean and re-build your project? You can do that with `CMD` + `Shift` + `K` (or by selecting **Clean** from the **Project** menu).